# Data accessing by double reverse filter with multiple interdependent model

Tags: python, django

I am working with some models in `Django`.

my `models.py`:

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Industry_Report(models.Model):
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    extra1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    extra2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    extra3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    extra4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.industry.name

class report_tableA(models.Model):
    industry_report = models.ForeignKey(Industry_Report, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    nid = models.IntegerField(blank=False, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

Now I am trying to access all those data of `report_tableA` which are interrelated to `Industry`'s object from the `Industry` model's `DetailView`.

my `views.py`:

```
class industryDetails(DetailView):

    model = Industry
    template_name = 'app/industryDetails.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Industry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Industry, user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        Industry_Report_obj = self.object.industry_report_set.all()
        context['Industry_Report'] = Industry_Report_obj
        report_tableA_obj = self.object.industry_report_set.report_tablea_set.all()
        context['report_tableA'] = report_tableA_obj

        return context
```

Actually, I try to implement a kind of double `reverse` approach [doc for relationship field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). But it won't work and say `Queryset not found` while loading the template. How can I access them by reverse approch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-case it's simpler to query the relationship in the other direction

```
report_tableA_obj = report_tableA.objects.filter(industry_report__industry=self.object)
```